# Error message - IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have daily data of rates for  different types of swap instruments. I am running the below code which takes the data for one type of instrument at each date and calculates a set of forward rates for each date:

```
for dt in AllDate:  
            data = importdata(location, dt, Curve, max_maturity = '30Y') 
            fwdrate = interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
            dictionary = {dt:fwdrate} 
            fwdsdic.update(dictionary)
```

The problem is that when I run the loop for one instrument, 6M EUR, I get the error message:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I don't get the error when I run the code for another set of instruments such as 3M USD or 6M GBP. The error message also says that there seems to be a problem with my `importdata' function, specifically the last line:

```
def importdata (fileloc, date, name, max_maturity):
    'Imports data from a given location, date and name'
    data = all_data
    data = data[ (data['date']) == date] # getting the date of the curve
    data =  data.loc[:, data.columns.str.startswith(name)] # getting the curve wanted at the date
    data = data.T # Transposing the data
    data = data.reset_index()
    data.columns = ['maturity','spot rate'] # renaming columns
    data['maturity'] = data.maturity.str.rsplit(n=1).str[-1]
    data = data.dropna()
    data = data.reset_index(drop = True)  
    data = data.iloc[:data.loc[data.maturity.str.contains(max_maturity,na=False)].index[0]+1]
     
    return data;
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is as it works for 3M USD and 6M GBP, but not 6M EUR.

An example of 3M USD data:

```
maturity    spot rate
0   1Y  0.213
1   2Y  0.287
2   3Y  0.498
3   4Y  0.762
4   5Y  1.012
5   6Y  1.2229999999999999
6   7Y  1.392
7   8Y  1.526
8   9Y  1.632
9   10Y 1.72
10  12Y 1.858
11  15Y 1.9869999999999999
12  20Y 2.0869999999999997
13  25Y 2.12
14  30Y 2.131
```

Example of 6M GBP data:

```
    maturity    spot rate
0   1Y  0.1228
1   2Y  0.2747
2   3Y  0.4234
3   4Y  0.5562
4   5Y  0.6675
5   6Y  0.7596
6   7Y  0.8375
7   8Y  0.898
8   9Y  0.9637
9   10Y 1.0172
10  12Y 1.09
11  15Y 1.169
12  20Y 1.214
13  25Y 1.2142
14  30Y 1.192
```

Example of 6M EUR data:

```
    maturity    spot rate
0   1Y  -0.539
1   2Y  -0.525
2   3Y  -0.486
3   4Y  -0.428
4   5Y  -0.359
5   6Y  -0.284
6   7Y  -0.207
7   8Y  -0.13
8   9Y  -0.055999999999999994
9   10Y 0.013999999999999999
10  11Y 0.08
11  12Y 0.141
12  13Y 0.196
13  14Y 0.244
14  15Y 0.287
15  16Y 0.32299999999999995
16  17Y 0.35200000000000004
17  18Y 0.376
18  19Y 0.395
19  20Y 0.41
20  21Y 0.42100000000000004
21  22Y 0.43
22  23Y 0.436
23  24Y 0.439
24  25Y 0.441
25  26Y 0.441
26  27Y 0.44
27  28Y 0.43799999999999994
28  29Y 0.435
29  30Y 0.43200000000000005
```

Comment: What error do you exactly get for the importdata function?

Comment: @schnaidar, there's not a problem when I run the importdata function for 6M EUR without the loop, but with the loop I get this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-d705bb9b81b3>", line 2, in <module>
    data = importdata(location, dt, Curve, max_maturity = '30Y')

  File "<ipython-input-15-6e2b9d810ba4>", line 12, in importdata
    data = data.iloc[:data.loc[data.maturity.str.contains(max_maturity,na=False)].index[0]+1]

  File "C:\Users\CH98HF\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3930, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0